# the particle も in 「ここには１人もしっている人がいません」

Tags: particle-も

> ここには １人（　　） しっている 人が いません。

(from #25 of http://jlpt.u-biq.org/3g1.html)

> A)　が　　　　　　B)　は　　　　　　C)　で　　　　　　D)　も

I know the answer is D, but what does the sentence mean? If しっている with kanji is 知っている, then I can guess the idea is "There isn't one person here I know"?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the sentence means exactly as you guessed.

> 「Indefinite word + も」 expresses either total affirmation or total negation.

「ひとり**も**いません」= "there is no one"

「ひとり**も**知{し}っている人がいません」= "there is no one that I know"

The sentence in question would make no sense whatsoever if any of the other three particles were inserted.

Other examples of this usage of 「も」:

**Total affirmation**:

「だれ**も**が知っているレストラン」("the restaurant that everyone knows of")

「ゴールデンウイークはどこ**も**混{こ}んでいる。」("Every place is packed during the Golden Week.")

**Total negation**:

「なに**も**知りません」("I know nothing.")

「もうだれ**も**愛{あい}せない。」(I could not love anyone any more.)